# how to query a local hbase instance

Tags: java, hbase

I followed the [hbase quick start](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html) and have a local hbase instance running.

I would now like to query it via java, as shown [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/client.html).

I have this right now:

```
Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table1 = new HTable(configuration, "table1");
table1.close();
```

But when I run it, the process starts, logs a bunch of stuff and never stops. How can I query my local instance from a standalone java app?

I've also tried adding this in, but it did not help:

```
configuration.set("zk-quorum", "127.0.0.1");
configuration.set("zk-port", "2181");
```

**EDIT #1**

It looks like if I'm a little more patient, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for table1,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:841)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:943)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:131)
```

I'm not using these properties:

```
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
configuration.set("hbase.master", "localhost:600000");
```

**EDIT #2**
This is my latest hbase-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///data/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/data/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your RegionServer is running fine. Do a quick jps to verify that. Also, in a local setup setting zk host and port is not required. But using it won't do any harm. Use

```
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
```

The third property is no longer required.

If the problem still persists please show me your log files.

Comment: I'm not sure how to start a local region server. I tried and I got this: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/0.98.1/libexec/bin/../logs/hbase-root-1-regionserver-user-mbp113.domain.hq.out
Password:
Password:
Password:
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
starting master, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/0.98.1/libexec/bin/../logs/hbase-root-master-user-mbp113.domain.hq.out

Comment: these are the commands I am using: local-regionservers.sh start 1
start-hbase.sh

Comment: If everything is running fine JPS should show you all the daemons, **HRegionServer** should be one among them along with its IP.

Comment: Yeah I get:
sudo jps
4756 Jps
4671 HMaster
4462 HRegionServer

Comment: You should also have **HQuorumPeer**. Looks like your ZK is not running. Also, it would be better to use some user other than root.

Comment: After the region server is turned on and distributed mode=true I get a password request, but no password works :\

Comment: This is because you haven't configured passwordless ssh and you are trying to run the daemons through **root** user, whose password you don't have. Try with some other user.

Comment: I thought that the localhost version started up zookeeper on it's own?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53923/discussion-between-javamonkey79-and-tariq)

Comment: Use  **bin/start-hbase.sh**. It starts all the processes automatically. If problem still persists, let's discuss it through chat...